# No logro mostrar por pantalla un array con todas las cadenas que contengan (-) en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de mostrar por pantalla un array de cadenas que contienen un guion medio (-). Deseo ingresar por pantalla muchas cadenas, con o sin el guion medio y luego frenar la operacion cuando ingreso "cancelar".

No me tira error, pero no me devuelve lo que estoy esperando, que es la lista con candenas que contengan el caracter guion medio. Desde ya, agradezco la ayuda. Noto que me termina devolviendo el ultimo valor ingresado con el caracter guion medio.

```js
mostrarCadenas = (unaCadena) => {
            let cadenasConGuion = [];
            for (i = 0; i < unaCadena.length; i++) {
                //let cadenasConGuion = [];
                cadenasConGuion = unaCadena.filter(unaSolaCadena => unaSolaCadena.includes("-"));
                //return cadenasConGuion;
            }
            return cadenasConGuion;
        }

        let cadenas = [];
        let cadena;
        while (prompt("Ingrese una cadena de texto") != "cancelar") {
            cadena = prompt("Ingrese una cadena de texto");
            cadenas.push(cadena);
        }

        console.log(mostrarCadenas(cadenas));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta ejecutas el `prompt` 2 veces en un mismo ciclo y en una de ellas no estás asignando el valor que regresa la función a la variable.

Precisamente aquí estás pidiendo un valor pero no lo guardas así que se pierde.

```
while (prompt("Ingrese una cadena de texto") != "cancelar") {
```

Una forma de arreglarlo sería:

```js
function mostrarCadenas(cadenas) {
    let cadenasConGuion = cadenas.filter(unaSolaCadena => unaSolaCadena.includes("-"))
    return cadenasConGuion
}

let cadenas = []
let cadena = prompt("Ingrese una cadena de texto")
        
while (cadena != null && cadena.toLowerCase() != "cancelar") {
    cadenas.push(cadena)
    cadena = prompt("Ingrese una cadena de texto")
}

console.log(mostrarCadenas(cadenas));
```

Por cierto, nota que quité el `for` porque  es innecesario. Ya que estás haciendo exactamente lo mismo y el resultado no cambia.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Mateo. Entendi todo el proceso y tus palabras fueron clarisimas. Esto me hace avanzar bastante con el lenguaje. Funciona correctamente.